# Can't get wireless to work on ubuntu 16.04 with Broadcom BCM43142 [14e4:4365]

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom

Tried [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214110) but no dice.

Also tried followed the steps [near the bottom of this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2321444) (which look similar) but on the last step I get:

```
$ sudo modprobe -v wl
insmod /lib/modules/4.10.0-32-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available
```

I'm not getting any kind of connectivity, and have to connect to my router with ethernet.

Here's my dpgk info:

```
$ dpkg -s bcmwl-kernel-source
Package: bcmwl-kernel-source
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: admin
Installed-Size: 7870
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Source: bcmwl
Version: 6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.1
Replaces: bcmwl-modaliases
Depends: dkms, linux-libc-dev, libc6-dev
Conflicts: bcmwl-modaliases
Description: Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source
 This package contains Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver
 for use with Broadcom's BCM4311-, BCM4312-, BCM4313-, BCM4321-,
 BCM4322-, BCM43224-, and BCM43225-, BCM43227- and BCM43228-based
 hardware.
Modaliases: wl(pci:v000014E4d00004311sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d00004312sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d00004313sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d00004315sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d00004727sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d00004328sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d00004328sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d00004329sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d0000432asv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d0000432bsv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d0000432csv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d0000432dsv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d00004365sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d00004353sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d00004357sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d00004358sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d00004359sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d00004331sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d000043a0sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d000043B1sv*sd*bc02sc80i*)
Original-Maintainer: Alberto Milone <alberto.milone@canonical.com>
```

Not sure what other information I should provide.